# How to plot multiple Poisson distribution in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to plot multiple Poisson (with different lambdas (1:10))

I found the following function to draw a plot

```
plot_pois = function(lambda = 5)
{
  plot(0:20, dpois( x=0:20, lambda=lambda ), xlim=c(-2,20))
  normden <- function(x){dnorm(x, mean= lambda, sd=sqrt(lambda))}
  curve(normden, from=-4, to=20, add=TRUE, col=lambda)
}
plot.new()
plot_pois(2)
```

[image]

But I can't plot another Poisson over it. I tried to change `plot` to `points` or `lines` but it totally changes the plot. I would also like to add a legends containing different colors for different values of lambda.

If I could plot it using `ggplot`, it would be a better option.

Comment: you have to remove the `plot` from the function, since you always call a new plot then. So first declare the plot and then you can add with `points` and `curve` new poisson distributions. A problem will be the boundarys since the xlim and ylim will stay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ggplot2 you can use `lapply` to loop over different lambdas:

```
library(ggplot2)
lambdas <- c(5, 2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0:20)) +
  lapply(lambdas, function(l) geom_point(aes(x = x, y = dpois(x, lambda = l), col = factor(l)))) +
  lapply(lambdas, function(l) stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = l, sd = sqrt(l)), 
                                aes(x = x, col = factor(l))))
```

Axes titles and limits, the legend title etc. can then be customized as usual in ggplot2.

Answer (score 9):

Another possible `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Build Poisson distributions

p_dat <- map_df(1:10, ~ tibble(
  l = paste(.),
  x = 0:20,
  y = dpois(0:20, .)
))

# Build Normal distributions

n_dat <- map_df(1:10, ~ tibble(
  l = paste(.),
  x = seq(0, 20, by = 0.001),
  y = dnorm(seq(0, 20, by = 0.001), ., sqrt(.))
))

# Use ggplot2 to plot

ggplot(n_dat, aes(x, y, color = factor(l, levels = 1:10))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = p_dat, aes(x, y, color = factor(l, levels = 1:10))) +
  labs(color = "Lambda:") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>